Apache Airflow for IoT device simulators
I want to use Apache Airflow for IoT device simulator written in python. Let's say I want to run that script for 25000 devices and the 25000 invocations should run concurrently. Is apache airflow is right tool to be used or there are other opensource tools which will be good fit in this use case?

Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are considered off-topic on serverfault. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  Software Recommendations SE community, but before posting, please read their guidelines. Alternatively the sites https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and/or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help might be better communities for reviewing your test architecture and approach
